# Python - Print and Seperator Function

Tags: python

**Question**: How can I automatically add commas between floats?

My issue is that I have floats in a dataset:

```
Dataset = [1.803 1.799 1.795 1.791 1.786 1.782 1.776 1.772 1.766 1.763 1.763 1.762]
```

What I want to do is add commas in between each number, and I've used:

```
print(Dataset, sep = ',')
```

Which does not work, as I have invalid syntax. The reason I want to add commas is because I have code after that can then convert them to strings, and it will be much easier if I can add the commas automatically rather than manual, which I've been doing.

I have looked into the Python API and most of the information is centered around adding commas between large numbers (So 1000000 to 1,000,000) rather than commas between floats.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of of Dataset?

Comment: Dataset  is invalid..

Comment: Can you include the output of `type(Dataset)` <-- just type that below where you have declared `Dataset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dataset = "1.803 1.799 1.795 1.791 1.786 1.782 1.776 1.772 1.766 1.763 1.763 1.762"
print(list(map(float,Dataset.split())))
>>>[1.803, 1.799, 1.795, 1.791, 1.786, 1.782, 1.776, 1.772, 1.766, 1.763, 1.763, 1.762]
```